# Brand-new Dell U3219Q monitor with relatively obvious yellow areas. Is it normal?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, images, colors

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogTdZ.jpg for better quality images.

I just got a Dell U3219Q and it's great. However, I almost immediately noticed that there are some areas/vertical stripes with quite noticeable yellow tint at the middle and middle-left of the screen, as shown in the photo attached below.

[image: 1]

I also tried to highlight the yellowish areas, though saving the edit on the photo seems to have made the colors a bit less obvious somehow. You may find the corresponding areas in the first image above.

[image: 2]

The yellow seems to be particularly salient when I have a white background (e.g. when trying to read texts on most websites).

I understand that there could be color imbalances in all monitors, but those look a bit too much to me.

After enabling uniformity compensation, the situation got a bit better (shown below). But to me the screen is a bit too bright with this on and my eyes hurt after a while.

[image: 3]

I'm not sure if this can be helped with display calibration tools. To me it looks like something inherent in the screen.

I wonder if what I'm experiencing within the normal range or if it is reasonable to hope for a better one if I exchange.

The calibration factory report is attached below. Apparently the red parts have relatively high delta.

[image: 4]

Comment: _"After enabling uniformity compensation, the situation got a bit better [...] But to me the screen is a bit too bright"_ - I guess that's how it's supposed to work, if the screen was uniform without compensation that feature wouldn't exist at all. Can you adjust brightness with compensation enabled?

Comment: Let it burn in for a week. Play some random Youtube at fullscreen constantly [or at least for several hours a day]  while you're not using it. See if it changes. it is displaying some poor uniformity lower left & right in your images far more noticeably than the yellow cast.

Comment: @Tetsujin True. I guess the middle of the screen was just the most salient since most website text is situated right there, and the yellow feels like a huge stain. Seems that this screen could just be in general of poor quality... and if it doesn't change I shall return it then.

Comment: If you bought in online, EU law says you have 14 days to change your mind & send it back, for any reason.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah. Just ordered another one to see if it would be any better. If both are not good enough I'll return both.

Comment: Just wanted to ask for some advice on whether what I'm seeing is within the normal range of deviation or if it's relatively outrageous... and that I'm not seeing things or being too sensitive.

Comment: tbh, the pictures are too small to really be able to tell. Wait for the 2nd one to arrive, send back the worst.. or both if they're both the same. I've 2 older Dells, both of which are really very good, so whether it's inherent in that model, or their QC has slipped over the years, I really couldn't say.

Comment: @Tetsujin You're right. I uploaded the better quality images at https://imgur.com/a/V4TbXTY The only problem with the order is that I bought the first one on Amazon, but they're now out of stock, so I won't get the cashback with my credit card if I keep the second order from a different seller... But I guess I can live with that.

Comment: Your profile says you live in the EU. It's EU **law** that you can return it. You don't even need to provide a reason, but if' you're returning it because it's faulty. **they** have to pay for the return postage charges & replace or refund. They cannot duck this responsibility.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, what I meant is that I get 3% cashback on my Amazon credit card for every purchase I make on Amazon, which would be gone if I returned the one bought from Amazon. But if it's inferior in quality there's nothing I can do.